# Getting the value of the selected row and column in the table using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to get the value of the column of a selected row using a button in each cell. Here's my Jquery,

```
$('.sampleBtn').click(function(){
  var row = $(this).closest('td');
  var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var id = row.find('.mainId').val();
  var level = row.find('.level').val();

  alert("Main ID "+id+" Job ID "+col+" Level "+level);
});
```

it functions properly when I used a clickable cell, but when I use a button, it always says that Im in column 3 even if I click the button in the other cells.

the tbody of the table in view,

```
 <?php foreach($mains as $temp): ?>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $temp->Main_ID; ?>"/><?php echo $temp->Main_Name; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="level">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" class="mainId" value="<?php echo $temp->Main_ID; ?>" />
      <input type="button" class="sampleBtn" value="Update" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have not updated `$(this)` references after changing the triggered DOM element. Scope of `this` for the button is the the `<input>` element, for the cell it is the `<td>`. So you need to update your `this` references in the script.

```
$('.sampleBtn').click(function(){
  var row = $(this).closest('td');
  // Changed *this* to *row* below to point at the <td>
  var col = row.parent().children().index(row);
  var id = row.find('.mainId').val();
  var level = row.find('.level').val();

  alert("Main ID "+id+" Job ID "+col+" Level "+level);
});
```

Comment: oh, that's what i forgot.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: I think that best way to get button index is:

```
var col = $('.sampleBtn').index(this);
```

Instead of:

```
var col = row.parent().children().index(row);
```

Try it:

https://jsfiddle.net/romadcxn/1/